# XSD either one element or the other

Tags: xml, xslt, schema, xsd

In XSD schema, I know I can define the sequence or element, choice of element, or required set that doesn't have to be in verbatim order, but is there a way to say a complex type should have either element John or element Jack, or none of them, and only if element John is present, should element Anna be possible to be specified once (but not required) at the same nesting level as John?

Possible scenarios:

```
<John /> | <John /> | <Jack /> | <!-- Neither. -->
           <Anna /> |          |
```

If yes, I suppose the following should also be possible to say:

```
<FolderPath /> | <MainFilePath />      | <!-- Neither. -->
               | <Sidekick1FilePath /> |
               | <SideKick2FilePath /> |
```

Again, neither is required, but once folder is specified, none of the files must be present, and when all of the files are specified, folder must not be specified. It should not be possible to specify one or two files only, either a folder or three files or nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by nesting choices and sequences. Optional contents ("neither" in your example) is done with `minOccurs="0"` cardinality. Cardinality restrictions can be used on element declarations or sets like here on `<xs:choice>` Sample type below.

```
<xs:complexType name="something">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="John" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Anna" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Jack" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked beautifully, but now I'm baffled as to how do I specify the choice should be a part of the outer sequence. So that I could have John+-Mikki, John and Anna+-Mikki, Jack+-Mikki or just Mikki. I tried to put it in :all, but it didn't work.

Comment: Couldn't vote your answer up due to low reputation. Sorry for that.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just go with xs:sequence and enforce the order of the elements. Thanks again.

Comment: If you still need help with the combination in your first comment, please update your question. Because of the restricted formatting possibilities in comments, it is quite hard to figure out what kind of combination you meant.
As a general advice, try to form the required orders in a finite state machine or think for a proper regex keeping (them deterministic). Such solutions are usually relatively simple to translate into schema code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help. However, I am okay with the solution you provided as it is. What I had in mind while writing my previous comment is not possible to achieve as it would not be deterministic.